# Creating an Array that contains multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have created two classes, one called "`Bucket`", and the other called "`Player`".

In "Bucket", I have a constructor method that creates a virtual bucket (i.e. small array) that contains three values - 1, 1, and 1. As well, I created a method to get the bucket array.

In the "Player" class, I have created a method that uses a larger array (I have called this larger array "ArrayOfBuckets"), which uses a loop to store a new bucket at each index value, up until a certain point (when i>NumberSticks). However, when I try to set

`ArrayofBuckets[i] = bucketInstance.getBucket();`

I get an error from Eclipse, saying that `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Bucket to int"`. I have spent an hour trying to solve this, to no avail. Any help would be really nice. Thanks a lot, and here is all the code that is used:

The Player Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public String name;
private int pType;
private int[] ArrayOfBuckets;

public Player(String tempName)
{
    this.name = tempName;   //this. is unneccessary
}

public void ArrayOfBuckets(int NumberSticks) //this is a constructor method and creates the arrays that contains a
{
    ArrayOfBuckets = new int[NumberSticks];
    int i = 0;
    while(i<NumberSticks) 
    {  
        Bucket bucketInstance = new Bucket();
        ArrayOfBuckets[i] = bucketInstance.getBucket();//new Bucket();      //ADD THIS
        i++;
    }     
}
```

and the Bucket Class:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Bucket {

//  private int[][] largeArray = null; //WTF DO I DO HERE
private int AIChoiceStick;
private int[] bucket;
private Random random = new Random();
private int CurrentScore[] = new int[51]; //at max, if 100 sticks are initially chosen, then each player takes at max 50 sticks, 
private int h = 0;                                                                         //^so why not have one more in case


public Bucket()
{
    bucket = new int[3];
    bucket[0] = 1;
    bucket[1] = 1;
    bucket[2] = 1;

public int[] getBucket()
{
    return bucket;
}
```

Comment: `public void ArrayOfBuckets(int NumberSticks)` is **not** a `constructor`.

Comment: Are you sure that you're showing us the code that gives you the problem?  Is it direct copy-paste or a modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're speaking about a two-dimensional array.

```
private int[][] ArrayOfBuckets;
```

Your ArrayOfBuckets (should be just *buckets* according to naming conventions) is an array of arrays, so it gets two sets of square brackets.

Then the initialization:

```
ArrayOfBuckets = new int[NumberSticks][3];
```

By the way, if you want to have room for 50 elements in an array, then initialize it *new int[50]* so it will have indexes 0 through 49.